# Odoo 9 / PDF Export / Useless border

Tags: html, css, odoo-8, qweb, odoo-9

In Odoo 9 (SAAS Version, hosted by Odoo themselves) i get a black line on every page in an exported pdf. The line (see image) is only visible in the pdf (digital and printed) not in a html mode.

Where the line/border comes from and how can i "delete" it? I tested different views and models while searched for css code which defines any kind of a border - no result. The problem occures in odoo 8 and now in odoo 9.

Have someone an idea how its possible to delete or hide this border?

[odoo pdf layout with useless border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A9zW.png)

Comment: Search the CSS files for `@media print` and the html files for `media="print`. Looks like a specific style for printing. Also look for any `<hr />` tag, which generates a simple line.

Comment: im not shure if this is possible - because of different issues and problems i migrated all to odoo 9 (hosted by odoo). Im not shure how to access there the orgin html and css files? :/

Comment: I went to the [Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/themes.html#create-a-specific-page-layout). following this tutorial to add a custom style, just add `@media print { hr {display: none;}}`

Comment: @Powermax1990 please paste your Qweb view XML file over hear so that your is much and more clear to understand.

Comment: I work not on a self hosted version of odoo 9 (directly hosted by odoo). How i get to these xml files? Or do you mean my html/ t-tags code of e.g. my bill?

Comment: just check with Qweb view on user inerface on view from configuration